# Doctrine @Assert Annotation Validation not working

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I have a document with the following field in Symfony / Mongo document definition:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 * @Assert\NotEmpty
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/([0-9]{4})/", message="Please use the YYYY format")
 * @Type("string")
 * Example "2014"
 */
protected $year;
```

However, whenever I create a new document and persist it to MongoDB, Doctrine doesn't enforce any Assert definitions at all... it allows just about any value to be saved for this field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assert (usually) has nothing to do with doctrine, it's sf2's validator component. You have to take care of validating your entities before persisting them

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Maerlyn. Yes, apparently, I need to do proper validation before I persist the document e.g.

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$violations = $validator->validate($myObj);
```